# Xcode crashes when I try to create a outlet from a UIWebview to Header file

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview

I am currently using Xcode 5 on my Macbook Pro which is running OSX Yosemite. I am trying to create an outlet from a UIWebview to a header file. When I let go of my mouse to create the connection, Xcode freezes and crashes. This is repeatedly happening no matter what I have done. I have tried restarting Xcode and my Macbook. Does anyone else have this problem or know how to fix it? Thanks!

I have added the logs from the crash(I couldn't include the backtrace because it exceeded the maximum characters in the body)

```
    Process:               Xcode [1631]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               5.1.1 (5085)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-5085000000000000~10
App Item ID:           497799835
App External ID:       520942841
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [1631]
User ID:               502

Date/Time:             2014-06-26 21:50:34.616 -0400
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10 (14A238x)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        6D3E70F1-91EB-79A5-FAB6-2929D7E8A66F

Sleep/Wake UUID:       C86C5452-A655-43AA-9D11-92BE0F080F3E

Time Awake Since Boot: 11000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       510 seconds

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 5B1008
ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/DVTFrameworks/DVTFrameworks-5074/DVTKit/ViewControllers/DVTControllerContentView.m:280
Details:  <DVTControllerContentView: 0x7fe687d170a0> can only have one subview, its contentView
Object:   <DVTControllerContentView: 0x7fe687d170a0>
Method:   -addSubview:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fe682d086a0>{number = 1, name = main}
Hints:   None


External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 1
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 4286
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=404.2M resident=289.4M(72%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=114.9M(28%)
Writable regions: Total=1.2G written=71.9M(6%) resident=141.4M(11%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=1.1G(89%)

REGION TYPE                        VIRTUAL
===========                        =======
Activity Tracing                     2048K
CG backing stores                    4084K
CG image                             19.3M
CG raster data                         92K
CG shared images                     1324K
CoreAnimation                         880K
CoreAnimation (reserved)               12K        reserved VM address space (unallocated)
CoreData Object IDs                  4100K
CoreImage                             264K
CoreUI image data                     180K
Dispatch continuations               4096K
Foundation                             16K
IOKit                                13.8M
IOKit (reserved)                        4K        reserved VM address space (unallocated)
Image IO                              700K
JS JIT generated code                   8K
JS JIT generated code (reserved)      1.0G        reserved VM address space (unallocated)
Kernel Alloc Once                       8K
MALLOC                              114.7M
MALLOC (admin)                         32K
Memory Tag 242                         12K
Memory Tag 249                        156K
Memory Tag 251                         80K
OpenCL                                 16K
OpenGL GLSL                           256K
SQLite page cache                    4352K
STACK GUARD                          56.1M
Stack                                15.7M
VM_ALLOCATE                          16.9M
WebKit Malloc                         464K
__DATA                               60.1M
__GLSLBUILTINS                       2588K
__IMAGE                               528K
__LINKEDIT                          100.5M
__TEXT                              304.0M
__UNICODE                             544K
mapped file                         152.6M
shared memory                          68K
===========                        =======
TOTAL                                 1.9G
TOTAL, minus reserved VM space      879.9M


Model: MacBookPro7,1, BootROM MBP71.0039.B0E, 2 processors, Intel Core 2 Duo, 2.4 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 1.62f7
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce 320M, NVIDIA GeForce 320M, PCI, 256 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x859B, 0x435435313236344243313036372E4D313646
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x859B, 0x435435313236344243313036372E4D313646
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x8D), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.24)
Bluetooth: Version 4.3.0d49 14130, 3 services, 16 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: Hitachi HTS545032B9SA02, 320.07 GB
Serial ATA Device: HL-DT-ST DVDRW  GS23N
USB Device: Built-in iSight
USB Device: Internal Memory Card Reader
USB Device: BRCM2046 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: IR Receiver
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
Thunderbolt Bus:
```

Comment: I have a feeling this is a Yosemite issue. Check your error logs. Also this _might_ be better for [this](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) exchange.

Comment: Thanks, I will ask my question there too... btw I'm 14 years old too! @Idris

Comment: Oh cool. I'm assuming you know how to take a look at the error logs?

Comment: Oh Ya, I can do that...

Comment: Try it on Xcode 6 and make the outlet.... Then switch back to Xcode 5 and continue working! That's it!

Comment: Did you create a bug report on apple about this?

Comment: I will make sure that I do that ASAP... Thanks @Jan

Comment: @Jan I just noticed that all my Xcode errors are automatically sent to apple...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should declare a IBOutlet in your header file. And then in Storyboard you try to connect the header file.

Comment: Although not the best thing to do, at least this worked for me.

Comment: I'ts a nice workaround, voted up as keeps me from opening both xcodes for this

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried to clean your product(Product->Clean)?
Then, open the xib file as source code and delete your IBOutlet info. Maybe XCode get confused about your IBOutlet.

Comment: maybe you can download a sample project from apple, if the sample project also crashes, then it's not your code's bug.